# PLS-00123: program too large (Diana nodes)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

Good Morning

I have oracle 10g when I compile a package I get this error:

PLS-00123: program too large (Diana nodes).

whereas this package has about 80 lines (spec) and 4500 lines in the body.

I have another package with 25k lines in the body but without any error when I compile it.

when I run user_object_size view and I get this:

```
  TYPE        SOURCE_SIZE    PARSED_SIZE        CODE_SIZE       ERROR_SIZE
    
   PACKAGE       4206            8260              4271           0 
   PACKAGE BODY  161144             0               0             42
```

**Note:**

1-when I compile this package in oracle 11g I didn't get any error.

2- I try to solve it by using :

```
     ALTER PACKAGE pakage_name COMPILE;

     ALTER PACKAGE pakage_name COMPILE DEBUG;
```

but also it didn't work.

Comment: Did you compile it with DEBUG? If so, try not to.

Comment: yes I try its but also it didn't work

Comment: You can't assume that a package with more lines of PL/SQL code will end up using more DIANA nodes.  A great deal depends on the complexity of the statements in those lines of code.  The only answer anyone is going to be able to give you, short of looking at the package and finding ways to simplify it, will be to break it up.

Answer (score 1):

> When a PL/SQL block, subprogram, package, or object type exceeds a size limit, you get an error such as `PLS-00123: program too large`. Typically, this problem occurs with packages or anonymous blocks. With a package, the best solution is to divide it into smaller packages.

**Edit after Justin Cave:**

> Unfortunately, you cannot estimate the number of DIANA nodes from the parsed size. Two program units with the same parsed size might require 1500 and 2000 DIANA nodes, respectively because, for example, the second unit contains more complex SQL statements.

"In other words, just because one package has more lines of PL/SQL code or has a larger parsed size doesn't mean it will have more DIANA nodes."

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/limits.htm)

Comment: Dear, I see this solution before but I think it's not clear to me because I have another package with 25k lines but it's didn't appear this problem.

Comment: Could you provide us your package's source code @M.Youssef

Comment: sorry I can't do that.

Comment: You may want to include the additional bit from the documentation "Unfortunately, you cannot estimate the number of DIANA nodes from the parsed size. Two program units with the same parsed size might require 1500 and 2000 DIANA nodes, respectively because, for example, the second unit contains more complex SQL statements."  In other words, just because one package has more lines of PL/SQL code or has a larger parsed size doesn't mean it will have more DIANA nodes.

Comment: the Final result I get it, it's doesn't matter how many package lines but how it's complex basically.
is that true?

Comment: Yes i think you can say that. @M.Youssef